# Tell browser to retain original base URL with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, proxypass, base-url

My BaseURL:   https://mywebsite.com/fun proxies to a nodejs app on http://localhost:3000 via an Apache virtualhost.

This is the response:

```
<html><body>
<a href="test.html">Click Me</a>
</body></html>
```

But when I hover over link in the browser, it shows https://mywebsite.com/test.html instead of https://mywebsite.com/fun/test.html

I've tried sending a **Content-Location:** header in my code but to no avail. I also added the /fun path to the end of ProxyPass.

I could fix this in my generated code and adding the base-url, but that would mean fixing all relative URLs even in templates I get. Would be painful. Any ideas how to fix?

Below is my Apache virtualhost

```
#
# Apache virtual host proxypass to localhost:3000
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com/public_html

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off

    ProxyPass /fun http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /fun http://localhost:3000

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Sample nodejs app.

```
//
// nodejs code running on 3000
//
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<a href="test.html">Click Me</a>')
})
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better solution, so here is my fix in case someone looking for same question:

```
    RewriteEngine  On
    RewriteRule "^/fun$" "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/fun/"  [L]
    ProxyPass "/fun/" http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse "/fun/" http://localhost:3000/
```